# How to check if an excel file contains a footer using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, add-in, excel-addins

my macro adds certain footers to my excel file, however if the footer is already applied i don't want to ask the user to choose the type of footer as it exists in the file.

is there any way to check if an excel file contains the footer using c#?

code where the footer is added to all the worksheets

```
                    foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in vstoWorkbook.Sheets)
                    {
                        if (ws.PageSetup.LeftFooter != FooterContent)
                        {
                            ws.PageSetup.LeftFooter = FooterContent;
                            ws.PageSetup.RightFooterPicture.Filename = @"image path";
                            ws.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&G";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isMatch = true;
                        }
                   }
                    Classified = true;
                    if (isMatch)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This document has already been classified");
                        //resetting the isMatch
                        isMatch = false;
                    }
```

Code where a popup appears where the user hasn't selected any footer

```
        if (!Classified)
        {
            classificationForm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: check contents of Sheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter, .CenterFooter, .RightFooter; if all empty then no footer? add more information and code to the question so we get a better idea what you're attempting to do

Comment: classified is always true, did you mean to check ismatch?